# Inverse Laplace Transform partial fraction $\frac{2}{s(s^2+s)}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Can anybody help me with the answer of this question?

> Find the inverse Laplace transform of:   $$\frac{2}{s(s^2+s)}$$

Comment: You need to clarify your notation. Do you mean $\frac{2}{s(s^2+2)}$? If so, place `\frac{2}{s(s^2+2)}` between dollar signs. Or maybe you meant $\frac{2}{s}(s^2+2)$; in that case, use `\frac{2}{s}(s^2+2)`. Either way, the $+2$ is a $+s$ in your title, contradicting your body.

Comment: Have you tried using partial fractions?

Comment: @J.G. i have updated my code

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$\frac{2}{s^2(s+1)}=\frac{2}{s}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+1}\right)=\frac{2}{s^2}-\frac{2}{s(s+1)}=\frac{2}{s^2}-\frac{2}{s}+\frac{2}{s+1},$$the fact that $e^{ax},\,xe^{ax}$ have respective Laplace transforms $\frac{1}{s-a},\,\frac{1}{(s-a)^2}$ implies the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{2}{s^2(s+1)}$ is $2x-2+2e^{-x}$.

Comment: in fact the complete formula is :  $\frac{2}{s(s^2+s)}$ -  $\frac{1}{(s^2+s)}$

Comment: @stackoverflowusername I did wonder why the problem had an unnecessary factor of $2$ in it. Fine: subtract out the inverse LT of $\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+1}$, i.e. $1-e^{-x}$. That gives you $2x-3+3e^{-x}$.